# Difference between elementary-education and primary-eduction?

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, we have the tags [elementary-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-education) and [primary-education](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primary-education). What is the difference? Should they be merged together? If yes, to which one of both?

Comment: I created primary-education in error; you should merge it with elementary education.

Comment: I think they should be synonyms the master tag should be **primary-education.**  This is an international standard term, and we use also [tag:secondary-education].

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in my comment I merged elementary-education into primary-education (and preserved the former as synonym of the later).